# What is the correct term for online fund transfer services?

Tags: paypal, terminology, currency

Services like PayPal, NETeller, Click2Pay, Moneybookers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Online Payment Solutions

Comment: Yeah, that *does* sound better.

Comment: Isn't there a one word term for it?

Comment: Online Payment Solutions is right, don't call 'em Payment Gateways

Answer (score 1):

"Online Fund Transfer Services", probably.

Answer (score 0):

These companies are called "Payment Service Providers", or PSPs.  See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_service_provider).